# MySQL Syntax Error(Joining Tables)

Tags: mysql, sql, join

can anyone tell me what is the error in this syntax???

```
SELECT crew_no AS Crew_No, concat( last_name, ', ', first_name, ' ', mi ) AS Crew_Name, pos_name AS Position, vesname AS Vessel,
FROM (
(
mastertb
JOIN positiontb ON ( positiontb.pos_code = mastertb.pos_code )
)
JOIN vesseltb ON ( vesseltb.vescode = mastertb.vescode )
)
ORDER BY crew_no
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: Uh... I'm pretty sure the *engine* is supposed to do that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
... AS Vessel, FROM ...
```

You should not have a comma before FROM.